# set value of a static field in Intent service

Tags: java, android

I have a static ArrayList categories in MainActivity. I want to load data to category in a IntentService which is call Retrofit 2 response.

when i debugged. Retrofit response work well it return a arraylist of category and add to categories but when I run the project the categories is null.

I donn't know why i get this error. Is there any way to fix it?

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG="MainActivity";

    public static User user = new User();
    public static ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context context;
    TextView textCartItemCount;
    AppInfomation appInfo;
    Retrofit retrofit;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;
        appInfo = new AppInfomation(context);
        retrofit = ApiClient.getApiClient();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GetCategoryService.class);
        startService(intent);
        ...
```

GetCategoryService.java.

```java
public class GetCategoryService extends IntentService {
    public GetCategoryService(){
        super("GetCategoryService");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getApiClient();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<ArrayList<Category>> getCategory = api.getCategories();
        try {
            Response<ArrayList<Category>> response = getCategory.execute();
            for(Category c: response.body()){
                MainActivity.categories.add(c);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("GetCategoryService", "Cannot call API");
        }
    }

    public void parseCategories(ArrayList<Category> cate){
        MainActivity.categories = cate;
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume your app continues to run all the time. You should save data to a local database like Room or Realm.

Comment: you're right the retrofit run asyn. I have fixed my problem